# How do I enable both a locked-screen and no HDMI signal to monitor?

Tags: screen-saver

I have the latest Raspberry Pi OS (Debian Bullseye) on a Raspberry Pi 4.  I want to achieve a setting whereby after a period of time the session will lock and no signal will get sent through HDMI so the monitor can switch to a sleep mode.

The default settings allow for the screen to blank (no signal sent to HDMI monitor so that the monitor can go into a sleep mode) after a period of time.  However, it does not lock the screen.  Xscreensaver allows for a lock screen but still sends a signal with a black image to the monitor such that the monitor will not sleep.

How do I achieve both a locked screen and no HDMI signal after [10] minutes of inactivity?

Answer (score 0):

[Seems like you want a configuration for DPMS (display power management signalling)](https://web.archive.org/web/20180129095655/http://webpages.charter.net/dperr/dpms.htm).
Also assuming you stick to X11 display, you can try the following command`xset q` to get your current settings.
To replace black screen with X11 logo on a blue background when screen blanking `sudo xset noblank`  .
To set the display to standby after 2 minutes, suspend after 5 minutes, turn off after 10 minutes of inactivity `sudo xset s 120 300 600` .

If none of these work you may try this [[tool](https://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/)][2](https://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/) and edit the Xscreensaver database file and edit the lock,locktimeout and dpmsOff parameters